# What are `lookup_keys` in Stripe?

Tags: php, stripe-payments, price

The [Stripe docs for "List all prices"](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/list) mention a [`lookup_keys` parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/list?lang=php#list_prices-lookup_keys). What kind of values does it expect?

I've tried passing a product ID, a plan/price ID, keywords... (test or dev.) But only end up with an empty array for the `data` property whenever I do.

Comment: according to doc, ``A lookup key used to retrieve prices dynamically from a static string. This may be up to 200 characters.`` https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/create#create_price-lookup_key

Comment: When you create a price (https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/create?lang=php), you need to manually assign a lookup key, so you can then use it to remember specific prices.

Comment: I don't find `lookup_keys` all that convenient because they cannot be set from the dashboard. (Which only allows for the setting of a "Price description" (AKA "nickname" in the API docs.)

Comment: I agree, it would be more useful if we could see and modify the `lookup_key` in the Stripe dashboard. Instead I have been using the `metadata` which can be set in the dashboard, and now it's possible to search by it:
`Stripe::Price.search({query: "metadata['my_string']:'my_value'"})`

Comment: So how do we set the lookup_key then if not in the dashboard? They talk about "better manage" and then can't even figure out how to set the value after hours of searching.

Comment: Nevermind, just wrote a method to do it. Seems you can use their CLI too? Anyway, not really convenient as you all were saying.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-shbqtjrRM0

Basically, if wish set a lookup key, in stripe shell you can do it:

```
stripe prices update "PRICE_ID" --lookup-key "NEW_LOOK_UP_NAME".
```

The PRICE_ID can found in dashboard (tab products - API ID).

Comment: The stripe dashboard now allows you to set a lookup key for each price. However, the dashboard doesn't seem to display the lookup key value after you save it. That said, the lookup key that I set in the dashboard seems to be working in my code.

Answer (score 1):

As @joelhaus wrote it is now possible to set it in the dashboard. Navigate to the product and then edit the price for a product. In the advanced section you can set the lookup key:
[image]